# Drools Rule depending on Knowledge from JDK Map (not within non-JDK Class)

Tags: java, hashmap, drools

I'm trying to write the below Rule, which depends on Knowledge provided in the below `main` that uses just a JDK [library] Map (instead of a Map within a non-library Class).  But it doesn't seem to be working...

Main method:

```
Map<String, Float> mapa = new HashMap<String, Float>();
mapa.put("Height", (float)1.73);
mapa.put("Weight", (float)79.0);
mapa.put("BMI", mapa.get("Weight") /
                (mapa.get("Height") * mapa.get("Height")));
ksession.insert(mapa);
```

rule.drl:

```
rule "Low BMI"
    when
        $map : (Map(values("BMI")) < 18.0)
    then 
        System.out.println("You have a low BMI");
end
```

I want to compare the value of BMI inside of rule precondition, if this condition is true, so I want to show the message below.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should write something like:

```
when
    $map: Map(this["BMI"] < 18)
then
```

It should work :)

Comment: +1, even I needed help with attributes for which properties dont work well.

Comment: Lists and maps at 5.8.3.3.8 (here is [5.8.3](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Beta2/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html#d0e4051) )

Answer (score 0):

In general, see Drools doc [7.8.3.3.10. List and Map access](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e7561) section...

FWIW:  Even though this below **more-simplified syntax** is not mentioned in that reference, I have anecdotally found [at least with Drools `6.2.0`] that this works (at least for `Map<String, Boolean>`, within the `ObjectUnderSpecification`):

```
rule "you rule name"
when
  ObjectUnderSpecification(mapKey == true)
then
  // RHS code
end
```

I have tested that to work.  Apparently the name of the Map that key is within doesn't even need to be referenced... I guess as long as *some* Map within `ObjectUnderSpecification` has the key, then that is what gets further evalutated.  *Please comment or edit in any reference if you find one that reflects what I've anecdotally found above.*

(I don't know if this could work similarly with nested Maps).

I would imagine that this type of syntax might also work with the `Map<String, Float>` from the Question here, something like this (but I haven't tested this one):

```
when
  $map: Map(BMI < 18)
then
```